FlutterCallkitIncoming - Event Listener not working when app is terminated
I implemented the FlutterCallkitIncoming ( CallKit - pub.dev ) in my project. The call screen using FlutterCallkitIncoming will show when the notification is received from the firebase. Until this everything works fine, the problem is arise when accepting the call on terminated state. It's working fine when the app is in foreground. The only problem is with the listener of the FlutterCallkitIncoming.
Could't find a solution in web or package documentation. Please solve this or give me a proper solution!!!
A fix for this issue or another package which work like this package but no issue like this.
Code is given below,

//initState of MyApp

@override
  void initState() {
    initializeCallKitEventHandlers(context);
    super.initState();
  }

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void initializeCallKitEventHandlers(BuildContext context) {
FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((CallEvent event) {
    switch (event!.event) {
      case Event.actionCallIncoming:
        // TODO: received an incoming call
        break;
      case Event.actionCallAccept:
        // TODO: accepted an incoming call
        // TODO: show screen calling in Flutter
        Provider.of<CallProvider>(context).startCall();
        break;
      case Event.actionCallDecline:
        // TODO: declined an incoming call
        break;
        ............
        ............
    }
  });
}

